# Exporting dataframe from R to Excel with styles and formatting

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, export

I would like to export a large table (similar to that shown in the image below) to Excel with parts of the string highlighted in few of the columns.

[image]

At present I am displaying the table columns using  `datatable` employing `rowCallback` function to highlight the sub string. Then to export the table to Excel, I am manually copying the rows from the displayed `datatable` to an Excel worksheet.

[image]

I could not accomplish this particular challenge using `openxlsx` or other libraries.

Please advice on how to overcome this challenge!

Comment: the `openxlsx` package has styling options. Check it out

Comment: `tidyxl` can read formatted cells [link](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tidyxl/vignettes/tidyxl.html)

Comment: The issue is exporting a dataframe with styles and format created in R to Excel without losing the styles and format.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to change the color of some specific characters with the code below. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDOMClient)

path_Excel_File <- "D:/empty_Excel_File.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

cell1 <- Sheets[[1]]$Cells(1,1)
cell1[["Value"]] <- "A"
cell2 <- Sheets[[1]]$Cells(2,1)
cell2[["Value"]] <- "B"
cell3 <- Sheets[[1]]$Cells(1,2)
cell3[["Value"]] <- paste0(LETTERS, collapse = "")
cell4 <- Sheets[[1]]$Cells(2,2)
cell4[["Value"]] <- paste0(LETTERS, collapse = "")

obj_Chars_11_To_14 <- Sheets[[1]]$Range("B2")$Characters(10, 4)$Font()
obj_Chars_11_To_14[["ColorIndex"]] <- 8
```

For the ColorIndex values, see https://www.automateexcel.com/excel-formatting/color-reference-for-color-index/.